# Cannot resolve JSON on android

Tags: android, json, okhttp

I'm having this problem with JSON and okhttp in android.
can anyone point me in the right direction? im new at this so any help would do.

[image]

This are my imports:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.*;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
```

Comment: what error you are facing ? Please put your error part of code and logcat and if possible photo also.

Comment: What is `JSON` in `RequestBody.create()` method ? Might be you have't made an object of `JsonObject` class...

Comment: Where does JSON comes from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the declaration of the  `JSON` reference:

```
public static final MediaType JSON
    = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

From the sample code in [the documentation](http://square.github.io/okhttp/):

```
public class PostExample {
  public static final MediaType JSON
      = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

  String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(body)
        .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
  }
}
```

Note that it's always a good idea to look at the documentation for the code you're using, in this case where you're calling `RequestBody.create()` you can look at [the documentation for this method](http://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/RequestBody.html#create(com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType,%20java.lang.String)), where you can see that the first parameter is a MediaType reference:

> public static RequestBody create(MediaType contentType,
>                    String content)
>
> Returns a new request body that transmits content. If contentType is non-null and lacks a charset,
>   this will use UTF-8.

Comment: thx man. i read that on android studio but didnt know it was a varible of type MediaType. i hope ill improve some day haha. ths again saved my day